# What's the term for calling a function this way？

Tags: php, syntax

```
unset $arr[$key];
```

Shouldn't it be :

```
unset($query[$key]);
```

Answer (score 3):

from the [**php manual**](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

> `echo` is not actually a function (it is a **language construct**)

same with `unset`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then it would be called a **language construct**, such as `echo`.

[What is the difference between a language construct and a "built-in" function in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in)

Answer (score 1):

**isset** and **unset** are actually implemented as PHP unary operators also, so they can be used without parens.