# PHP hidden trick or a supported feature?

Tags: php, language-features

I know that to concatenate strings in php, a dot should be used:

```
echo 'hello' . ' world'; // hello world
```

But incidentally i typed this:

```
echo 'hello' , ' world';
```

and the result was still hello world without any errors.

Why is it so?
Can we also concatenate using comma?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's documented in the entry for [`echo`](http://php.net/echo):

> void echo ( string $arg1 [, string $... ] )

The two forms are not actually equivalent, since there's a [difference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php#78898) in the instant in which functions are evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot concatenate with comma:

```
<?php

$foo = 'One', 'Two';

?>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   ','

Answer (score 1):

`echo` is a language construct, so you don't need parenthesis. But you are "passing" multiple parameters to echo. Think of it as:

`echo('hello', ' world');`

Comment: @bzim language construct. At least I didn't say it "flattened the array" ;)

Comment: But that's exactly what it did. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's no hidden trick, it's just how echo works. If you have a look at the PHP reference docs for [echo](http://www.php.net/echo), you'll notice that it will echo the list of strings that you throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

echo is a language construct. It is in someway a special function that's defined at Grammar level (I might be wrong on this). It is a function that somehow doesn't follow any of the defined way of defining a function/method as an example and the way of calling them. It "by-passes" some syntax check :)

There's a nice post discussing the [difference between language construct & built in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in) here in StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo('hello', ' world');
```

It's the same as:

```
echo 'hello', ' world';
```