# Making Values Lower-case and stripping slashes

Tags: php, echo

I am pulling values submitted from a form and displaying them in a couple different formats.  Sometimes I need the values to be echo-ed in lowercase and sometimes I need any capitalization preserved, depending on the section of the page.  However, I need all values to have the slashes stripped out.

I am using the following format to echo the lowercase values

```
<?php echo strtolower ( $keyword ); ?>
```

This is working fine.  Though, adding 'stripslashes' to that is throwing an error.  I'm sure I'm not formatting it correctly.

How do I accomplish both of these items?

**Update**

I was simply asking a question related to PHP formatting and syntax but, in order to appease Oli Charlesworth . . .

```
<?php echo stripslashes strtolower ( $keyword ); ?>
```

This is the code I had tried.  And this is the error it was throwing ...

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/content/u/s/e/username/html/folder/code.php on line 63**

Comment: Argh, another "Here is some code that works.  I have some other code that doesn't work.  What is the problem?".  What is your problematic code?  And what is the error?

Comment: Use example one from Alex or myself - you need to nest the function calls is all.

Comment: This question hints at a misunderstanding of the language syntax. You should read a [few tutorials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554936/php-recommended-tutorials) before you venture into other topics and **download** the php manual.

Comment: @mario - Agreed.  I am a PHP novice.  I simply posted this question based on time restraints.  I needed to get this to production.

Comment: These are not "slashes", they're "backslashes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo strtolower(stripslashes($keyword));
```

Should do it.

Also note, you could do...

```
<span style="text-transform: lowercase"><?php echo stripslashes($keyword); ?></span>
```

#### Update

Your code...

```
<?php echo stripslashes strtolower ( $keyword ); ?>
```

...is not correct code, because each function needs to take its arguments within parenthesis. You need to wrap them in their respective parenthesis - so the return value from the inner becomes the argument for the outer.

Comment: Thank you for actually providing a useful answer :)

Comment: "because each function needs to take its arguments within parenthesis"

except `echo`

Comment: @bart `echo()` isn't a function, but a [language construct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in) (or more generally, an operator).

Answer (score 1):

You really need to provide the code you are using to stripslashes before we can assist properly.

But the following code should stripslashes:

```
<?php echo strtolower(stripslashes($keyword)); ?>
```

I cant think of any reason why that wouldn't work unless you are using an ancient version of PHP. You could also use (although this will remove all slashes including //):

```
<? echo strtolower(str_replace("\\", "", $keyword)); ?>
```

You will need to utilise some kind of conditional to decide when to keep capitals or not.

Comment: Your second example is not the same as how `stripslashes()` works.

Comment: I know - thats why i said it will remove all slashes including a double slash.

Comment: McCann Sorry, I meant `stripslashes()` works on `\ `, not `/`. I also think the OP would be in a bit of trouble if they were still using PHP3 :)