# PHP: What's wrong with this line of code?

Tags: php, syntax

```
if($player[$x]->name == $p->name || $player[$x]->name == $target) unset $player[$x]; //<-- line 215
```

commenting out this line removes the error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '(' in /path/script.php on line 215
```

But I don't see were it's expecting a (, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: [What is the difference between a language construct and a “built-in” function in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`unset()`](http://php.net/unset) is a language construct that requires parentheses; you must use `unset($player[$x]);`.

Answer (score 5):

unset is a function, you need to call it with parentheses, like this:
unset( $player[ $x ] )

you'd better separate your code to different lines to see where the problem is more easily.

Comment: `unset()` is a language construct invoked like a function.

Comment: +1.5 for suggesting OP separate code onto multiple lines for readability, -0.5 for saying unset is a function, when it is actually a language construct

Answer (score 3):

Unset requires the parentheses:

```
if($player[$x]->name == $p->name || $player[$x]->name == $target) unset($player[$x]);
```

Comment: This is completely pedantic (aka ignore me), but in the interest of completeness, I found while writing my answer that `unset()` is not actually considered a function. From the PHP manual: "Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions". http://php.net/unset