# php echo does not need parenthesis

Tags: php, function, echo

since echo is not a function, we do not use parenthesis when calling it.

example:

```
echo "hello";
```

as opposed to

```
echo ("hello");
```

If it were to be a function, it would have been forced to be called as `echo ("hello");`

In ASP/Vbscript, I can call a function one of the following ways;

```
call dosomething("x","y","z")

dosomething "x","y","z"   notice the missing parathesis
```

The closest thing I have seen to this parenthesis-free syntax in PHP is the echo. I like the ability to skip the parenthesis.

My question to you is if there is a way to write a function in PHP, that would not require the use of the parenthesis?

Comment: `echo` is not a function but rather a "language construct" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) that's why you can use with without parenthesis.  Check out the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in

Answer (score 12):

From within PHP? **No**.

You'd need to modify the C code in the Zend Engine. This is of course undesirable as you would need to use a custom build to run your code. It would also be confusing needlessly to other programmers. You should not try to change core language features simply because you like the ability to skip tokens.

The parenthesis are important to denote function invocation.

Things such as `echo`, `include`, etc are called *language constructs*. The way they are implemented in the language are similar to normal unary operators such as `new`, `++` etc.

Note too that language constructs do not strictly omit the parenthesis. Take `unset()` for example.

Comment: "No" would suffice as the question asked specifically about writing "a function in PHP".

Comment: @salathe Is fleshing out an answer frowned upon?

Comment: Only when it takes the answer off-topic.

Comment: @salathe I don't believe it has here. I told the OP *how* it could be done and the disadvantages of doing it.

Comment: which does not answer the question asked.

Comment: @salathe *...is [there] a way to write a function in PHP, that would not require the use of the parenthesis?* to which I answered *Not without modifying the C code in the Zend Engine*. Seems like an answer to the question to me. I'll explicitly add the *not in PHP* part if it helps you.

Comment: @adam anything bar the first paragraph (or first sentence before your edit) is superfluous for this question.

Comment: @salathe Sure, but we'd never have great answers (not implying this one is) if people only posted *yes* or *no*.

Comment: If the question is answered by "yes" or "no" then that is a *great answer*.  The ubiquitous apparent need to "flesh out" answers here on SO is disappointing.  Adding fluff for the sake of *appearing* to be a more thought-out, satisfactory or otherwise better answer—to game the OP into accepting yours over others—is something I heartily dislike about this site.

Comment: @salathe I'd much rather learn the answer to my questions and then some more relevant information. I'll just disagree and leave it at that. Also, believing I added the extra information to be accepted over the other answers is a presumption and an incorrect thought.

Comment: Fair enough. I stand corrected in this individual case, clearly.

Comment: I see your point salathe, but I prefer a more in depth answer like the one Alex gave. I would have hated if the answer was just a yes or no. Take the yes case. Is that going to cause me to ask another one asking "how then?". Also, many times, a simple yes|no is very misleading.

Answer (score 2):

no. "Echo" is not a function in php, but a language construct, that's why you can use it without parens. The same goes for "include" or "require", you can use them with or without parens.

Answer (score 0):

echo() is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it.

More about echo can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php