# PHP echo correct input syntax

Tags: php, string, echo

I can't seem to find a straight up answer on this…
Lets say I want to echo "Stack Overflow FTW" to the screen. Should I use

```
echo ('Stack Overflow FTW');
```

or

```
echo 'Stack Overflow FTW';
```

If it doesn't really matter, which one would be the best one to get into the habit of using?

Comment: It's much simple to write the 2nd option without having a bracket

Comment: There is afaik now difference between this two version so go with the easier (2nd) one.

Comment: but it will matter using double/single quoation. If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special char.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php echo does not need parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748613/php-echo-does-not-need-parenthesis)

Comment: Did any of these answer your question @JacobLukeWood ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` isn't actually a function in PHP, it's a language construct. This means that parentheses are not required and as such I would recommend not using them as they just add clutter.

Comment: You can read more here: http://php.net/echo

Answer (score 3):

Why ask people and not ask the Language docs? Opinions don't matter here, language syntax does.

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses.
>
> echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.

Source: [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/echo)

Answer (score 1):

### No that really doesn't matter.

**`echo`** is a language construct and it does not require parenthesis [*They are optional*]. If you don't wanna type much. You can very well go with your second option.

Answer (score 1):

My personal opinion is that you should always go for what is more readable! In this case it might seem like no big issue but if you are echoing the return values of methods or building more complicates strings, things tend to get messy.

Be aware though that code readability and simplicity usually go hand in hand. If you want to be consistent, use parenthesis (not brackets)!

Comment: Thanks, you made the answer clear.
Also, thanks TiMESPLiNTER for your answer on the variables :)

Answer (score -4):

```
echo "Stack Overflow FTW";
```

Using double quote means it is a string.

Comment: Single quotes make it a string too, and this does not really answer the question.

Comment: Single quotes also make it a string. But with double quotes PHP searches after variables inside the string and replace them. With single quotes PHP don't touch the string.

Comment: Oh, thanks TiMESPLiNTER, good to know :)
Which ones should I usually use?