# Why does [] fail on a literal array?

Tags: php

PHP array()[]= fails:

```
<?php
// PHP Version => 5.6.13
$e=array()[]=1;       // REJECTED "E_COMPILE_ERROR : type 64 -- Cannot use [] for reading "
$d=array();$e=$d[]=1; // Workaround - accepted
```

despite the manual saying that [array() returns an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) and that [*somearray*[]= assigns a value to an array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Why?

Comment: *"An **existing** array can be modified by explicitly setting values in it."* In your first example your array does not exist yet.

Comment: It does. array() creates it, it exists, and then [] attempts to access it.

Answer (score 1):

`array()` is a [language construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in), not a function. it doesn't actually `return` an array like a function does, it creates an array internally, which is a temporary expression. You have to assign it to a variable first to interact with the array.

PHP7 has a [better error for this](https://3v4l.org/n4NpD)

> Fatal error: Cannot use temporary expression in write context

Comment: "it doesn't actually return an array like a function does". It is however defined to return an array (see the docs I quoted), and that should be sufficient, regardless of whether this is 'like a function does'. Hence I conclude there's a bug - a failure of behaviour and documentation to accord.

Comment: @ChrisJJ It's not a bug … saying that as a core contributor to the PHP engine here. You cannot use arbitrary expressions where a variable-like value is expected. Variable-like values are function calls, property and array dereferences of other variable-like values.

Comment: "It's not a bug. You cannot use arbitrary expressions where a variable-like value is expected." That does not accord with the published language spec. The language spec doesn't say a variable-like value is required here.

Comment: "PHP7 has a better error for this. Fatal error: Cannot use temporary expression in write context" I can't imagine why you think this is better. Or even appropriate. array() is not a temporary expression. It's permanently there in the source, as might be e.g. myfunc(), 1+1.