# What is a temporary expression in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling

When I run the following code,

```php
<?php

const nums = [1, 2, 3];
nums[0] = 50;
```

it gives me the following error:

```text
Fatal error: Cannot use temporary expression in write context in <file> on line 4
```

My question is **what exacty is a temporary expression in PHP?** I've tried searching the documentation of PHP for an answer but there is nothing mentioned there regarding this error.

I just can't understand what exactly does this error mean?

Comment: `nums` is const. Modifying it defeats the point

Comment: I know that. I am trying to make intuition of the error message.

Comment: FWIW, PHP error messages sometimes tend to be obscure and nonsensical. It's referring to some internals which shouldn't really matter to you. The error is that you're trying to modify a constant, which you simply can't. The error message just does a terrible job telling you that. — Still an interesting question about PHP internals, if that's what you're after…

Comment: your problem is because you're using ```const``` which means your array is now immutable and can't be changed, change your code to this: ```$nums = [1, 2, 3];```

Comment: I'm guessing `nums[0]` is the temporary expression in question puting it on the left of an `=` puts it in "write context"

Comment: @Jens I tried reading that question and its answer but it's something unrelated to my question.

Comment: I suppose not assigning to a *variable* starting with `$` is always an error. Expression like `foo[bar]` are apparently "temporary expressions" in PHP because… internals. Having those appear on the left hand side of a `=` is the error.

Comment: Ok, can we close this question now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40540148/487813 also may be helpful

Answer (score 2):

This message is a bit of a leaked internal. If you look for the string in [PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src), you'll find explicit unit tests that illustrate the error being thrown in these contexts:

- Enum prevent unsetting value

  ```
  enum Foo: int {
      case Bar = 0;
  }

  unset(Foo::Bar->value);
  ```
- Passing a dimension fetch on a temporary by reference is not allowed

  ```
  $fn = function(&$ref) {};
  $fn([0, 1][0]);
  ```
- Passing a property fetch on a temporary by reference is not allowed

  ```
  $fn = function(&$ref) {};
  $fn([0, 1]->prop);
  ```
- Writing to a temporary expression is not allowed

  ```
  [0, 1][0] = 1;
  ```

The message is confusing because it isn't directly triggered by writing to a constant. In fact, `FOO = 2;` alone is a parse error.

Comment: These are instances where I don't like PHP. It's overall a decent language, but has really surprising design features at times.

Comment: To be fair, error messages are rarely the strong point of any language. But PHP doesn't have anything as terrible as Node's "Error: ENOENT" ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you.