# Custom PHP function passing arguments without brackets

Tags: php, function

I got an unusual question.. 
When we pass arguments into a PHP function, we always uses round brackets, ie :

```
function myFunction($argument){ 
  return $argument; 
}
```

and we call it with

```
myFunction($argument);
```

Have anyone managed to create a custom PHP function where by passing arguments / parameter wihtout braces, similar to something like echo.. ie:

```
myFunction $argument;
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in.

Comment: In a function definition you have a list of variables. They are called **parameters**. But, when you are calling a function you are passing a list of values (one for each defined parameter). These values are called **arguments** ;-)

Comment: [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) [is not a function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php#refsect1-function.echo-notes).

Comment: Not 'real' PHP, but If you really want to try - https://www.sitepoint.com/php-macros-for-fun-and-profit/ may be able to do something for you (Disclaimer - not for beginners, intermediate or advanced users - just for people who don't want to do this sort of thing for a living ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [PHP language specifications](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/00-specification-for-php.md#specification-for-php), the [Function calls](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/13-functions.md#function-calls) section mentions:

> A function is called via the function-call operator [()](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#function-call-operator).

The syntax of a [Function Call Expression](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#function-call-operator) is:

> function-call-expression:
>       [qualified-name](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/09-lexical-structure.md#grammar-qualified-name)   (   [argument-expression-list](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#grammar-argument-expression-list) <sub>opt</sub>   )
>       [callable-expression](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#grammar-callable-expression)   (   [argument-expression-list](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/10-expressions.md#grammar-argument-expression-list) <sub>opt</sub>   )

As you can see, a function call expression is made from function name (either the name as a token or a PHP expression that evaluates to it) followed by open parenthesis (`(`), an optional list of arguments (separated by comma (`,`)), followed by the close parenthesis (`)`).

The parentheses are required and they allow the compiler tell apart a constant from a call of a function without arguments. They also allow it to understand that `$var()` is a function call while `$var` is not.

---

#### Have anyone managed to create a custom PHP function where by passing arguments / parameter wihtout braces, similar to something like `echo`?

The short answer is **"No, this is not possible in PHP"**. Above is explained why not.

---

[`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is not a function, it [is a language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php#refsect1-function.echo-notes). The same for [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php), [`include`/`include_once`/`require`/`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Using `echo` with parenthesis is possible but, in fact, the parenthesis are not part of the `echo`, they are part of the expression that is printed by `echo`.

The following code is invalid:

```
echo('one', ' ', 'two');
```

It would be valid if `echo` were a function.

Look at this code:

```
echo('one'), ' ', ('two');
```

This is apparently invalid PHP error code. And it would be invalid if `echo` were a function. But `echo` is not a function and the code is valid.

Let's assume, for a moment, that `echo` is a function and the language allows calling functions with or without parentheses. The line above is ambiguous. What are the arguments of `echo`?

Should the compiler think the call to `echo` is `echo('one')` or `('one')` is just a string in parentheses (a perfectly valid expression) and the arguments of `echo` are `('one')`, `' '` and `('two')`?