# regarding an "IF" statement, is "if" a function?

Tags: php, coding-style, programming-languages

This is sort of a general programming question. However, realizing that the IF conditional is used in many languages, keep in mind I primarily use PHP.

And in PHP, if statements look like:

```
if(some comparison is true) {code to process;}
```

"if" in this case is laid out like a function:

```
function function_name(arguments) {code to run;}
```

except that the code does not rely on if the arguments are TRUE or not. It just runs when you "call" it.

So is "if" really a sort of function? Just trying to think outside of the proverbial box here.

Comment: No, `if` is a language construct not a function. This post goes into a good explanation on the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180184/what-is-the-difference-between-a-language-construct-and-a-built-in-function-in

Comment: educational. thank you everyone. i learn more and more each day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking: no. It is a [language construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

PHP does even have docs on specific keywords, [like if](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

Since you were asking for "sort of": That kind of depends on your definition of "sort of". For organizing in your mind how it works you can think like that, but it might also be a pitfall since for example the scope for variables is not only inside the if-block (like it would be in a function), amongst other concerns.